# How to achieve this animated effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

After visiting the website for Google atmosphere this year, I found a very engaging little feature, I was wondering if anybody could give me a rough idea as to how the animated effect of the circling bubbles is achieved, I'm not interested in their ability to do anything other than hover round in a circular path.

The link to the site is here https://atmosphere.withgoogle.com/

How would you create a number of circles with random movement around a circle path and how is the animation of the circles connecting with each other achieved

Comment: how are there too many possible answers i'm asking what they used to do it and what the principle behind the animation is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the bubble animation on the website you can see that the animation is using the HTML5 canvas element in order to draw and animate the bubbles. There are a number of ways you might be able to accomplish that rotation effect. Below I have shown one possible approach that animates a single circle in a loop. In order to achieve the full functionality that the website has would obviously require something more sophisticated, but it should allow you to have a basic idea of how that could be accomplished.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var circlePosX = 40;
var circlePosY = 60;
var radius = 10
var rotationSpeed = 0.025;
var canvasCenterX = canvas.width/2;
var canvasCenterY = canvas.height/2;

// Begin Canvas Animation
window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);

function drawFrame() {
    
    // Clear Canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        
    // Draw Circle
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(circlePosX, circlePosY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    
    // Rotate Canvas Around Center
    context.translate(canvasCenterX, canvasCenterY);
    context.rotate(rotationSpeed);
    context.translate(-canvasCenterX, -canvasCenterY);

    // Continue Animation
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="150" style="border: 1px solid black" />
```

There is a good resource on MDN about creating animations using the canvas element if you would like to learn more. Here is the link: [Basic animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations)

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you